# Is there a way using Joystick to login in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, authentication, raspberry-pi, pam, joystick

I recently bought [Adafruit OLED Bonnet](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3531?gclid=CjwKCAjw9r-DBhBxEiwA9qYUpRUJeEy2nVnIBAtqa2wYvMi4u8TYABvNydk7ikvfJEr2hsfqkgGloBoC0OkQAvD_BwE). It has a joystick and 128x64 OLED display. I'm trying to add a simple login mechanism with joystick and this OLED display, so that I don't need plugin my keyboard and display, something like pin number or Morse Code or the sequence of inputs.

Can I run some python code before login, and if it returns success, Pi will log in?

Comment: You can write a PAM module. But that usually done in C.

Comment: Thanks! @KlausD. Is there any example or tutorial I can learn?